# In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to rank the rownames of `Mc` with respect to their association with the factor of interest to identify the rownames that are least associated with the factor of interest based on FDR-adjusted p-value.

```
library(missMethyl)

df <- rbind(clin$subtype, meth)
rownames(df)[rownames(df) == "1"] <- "subtype"
rownames(clin.info) <- clin.info$Sample.ID
type <- as.character(head(df, n=1))
type.df <- head(df, n=1)
group <- factor(type, levels=c("1a", "1b", "1c", "2a", "2b", "2c"))
mat <- apply(as.matrix(df), 2, as.numeric)
rownames(mat) <- rownames(df)
rownames(mat) <- make.names(rownames(mat), unique=TRUE) # Keep only unique indices
mat <- mat[-1,]

# extract Illumina negative control data
INCs <- getINCs(rgSet)
head(INCs)

# add negative control data to M-values
Mc <- rbind(mat,INCs)
# create vector marking negative controls in data matrix
ctl1 <- rownames(Mc) %in% rownames(INCs)
table(ctl1)

rfit1 <- RUVfit(Y = Mc, X = group, ctl = ctl1) # Stage 1 analysis
rfit2 <- RUVadj(Y = Mc, fit = rfit1)

top1 <- topRUV(rfit2, num=Inf, p.BH = 1)
```

The `topRUV` function in missMethyl:

```
topRUV <- function (fitsum, number = 10, sort.by = c("p","F.p"), p.BH = 1){
  
  tab <- fitsum$C
  
  if (p.BH < 1) {
    
    sig <- (tab[,grepl("p.BH_", colnames(tab))] < p.BH)
    
    if (any(is.na(sig)))
      sig[is.na(sig)] <- FALSE
    
    if (all(!sig))
      return(data.frame())
    
    tab <- tab[sig,]
  }
  
  sort.by <- match.arg(sort.by)
  
  ord <- switch(sort.by, p = order(tab[,grepl("p_", colnames(tab))], 
                                   decreasing = FALSE), 
                F.p = order(tab$F.p, decreasing=FALSE))
  
  if (nrow(tab) < number)
    number <- nrow(tab)
  
  if (number < 1)
    return(data.frame())
  
  top <- ord[1:number]
  
  tab[top,]
}
```

Warning:

```
Warning message:
In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

Output:

```
> dput(head(top1))
structure(list(F.p = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), F.p.BH = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p_X1.1b = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p_X1.1c = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p_X1.2a = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p_X1.2b = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p_X1.2c = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p.BH_X1.1b = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p.BH_X1.1c = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p.BH_X1.2a = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p.BH_X1.2b = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), p.BH_X1.2c = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b_X1.1b = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b_X1.1c = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b_X1.2a = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b_X1.2b = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b_X1.2c = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), sigma2 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), var.b_X1.1b = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), var.b_X1.1c = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), var.b_X1.2a = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), var.b_X1.2b = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), var.b_X1.2c = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), fit.ctl = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mean = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c("NA", "NA.1", "NA.2", "NA.3", 
"NA.4", "NA.5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Data:

```
> dput(meth[1:20,1:20])
structure(c(5973.04545454545, 7167, 392.5, 284.5, 318, 1597, 
265, 902.5, 9502, 271, 734, 596.5, 13718.7142857143, 8362.5, 
3241, 180.5, 8508.5, 243, 1165, 6875.5, 8666.675, 11621, 789.5, 
498, 221, 1698, 346, 1135.5, 12915, 342.5, 996.5, 944.5, 15746.9090909091, 
11234.5, 6025.5, 384, 8506, 924, 1469.5, 9683.5, 12066, 17117, 
1428.5, 427.5, 340, 5309, 263, 3676.5, 11848, 182, 2859.5, 888.5, 
14769, 11703.5, 5866.73076923077, 403, 12173.7380952381, 1220.5, 
2290.5, 13350.5, 9549, 12351.5, 1971.5, 348, 137, 4438, 313, 
928, 11267.5, 208, 523.5, 943.5, 14859.6, 10113.7692307692, 4842, 
206.5, 8810.5, 1015, 1630.5, 9540, 6652.5, 9717, 968.5, 432.5, 
244, 4337.5, 274, 1360.5, 10625.5, 293, 1117.5, 990.5, 14038.75, 
11348.9545454545, 5358, 315.5, 9496.5, 781.5, 2093, 7478.5, 8074.5, 
12065, 2346, 346.5, 184, 2698, 108, 1382, 10971, 395.5, 703, 
1043.5, 13599, 9665.75862068966, 4509, 187.5, 10092.25, 849, 
1443, 10186.5, 5197, 7957, 397, 293.5, 222, 4991, 325, 578.5, 
8353.13157894737, 251, 423.5, 638, 11114.1, 7770.5, 3726.5, 182.5, 
6943.5, 483.5, 846, 7054, 10458.5, 16403.5, 946, 367.5, 207, 
2409, 382.5, 2098.5, 11727.1666666667, 261.5, 1073, 1041.5, 14848.5, 
11306.5, 4929, 279.5, 10950.5, 1357, 1435.5, 12343, 10286.5, 
16054.5, 2091, 413, 394, 4791, 357.5, 6139, 11416, 142.957627118644, 
1037, 1094, 15232.2, 11021.4615384615, 5517, 435, 9287.5, 1150.5, 
1541, 13360, 12780.3571428571, 18653, 1774, 430, 549.5, 6791.5, 
365.5, 3242.5, 14157.5, 178.5, 1958.5, 1943, 18427.6153846154, 
15743.5, 7570.5, 435.5, 15171, 1608, 2512, 14185.5, 6694.51315789474, 
8770, 695, 575.5, 326.5, 2239.5, 453.5, 4217, 11313.5416666667, 
241.5, 4251, 2726.5, 14482.6666666667, 12086.2380952381, 5777.5, 
791.5, 10104.5, 8236.52380952381, 3342, 7411.5, 7627.5, 10499, 
856.5, 266, 228, 2575, 241.5, 1322.5, 11050, 257, 831, 620.5, 
13578, 9071.91304347826, 2460.53846153846, 115, 7487.25, 890, 
1546.5, 9733, 13844.5, 20279, 3507.5, 369.5, 685.5, 2467, 258.5, 
3740.5, 13383.7962962963, 319.5, 1126.5, 1198.5, 16496, 13498.5, 
6712.5, 460.5, 12652.5, 728, 4075.5, 15116.5, 9306.5, 16481, 
668, 247.5, 443.5, 5570.5, 321, 5629, 11220.5, 261.5, 724, 1039.5, 
14691.8571428571, 11260.6666666667, 5729.8125, 309.5, 12197, 
1089.5, 1524.5, 12096.5, 12358, 17694, 1146, 531.5, 171, 2018.5, 
267.5, 4390, 11672.75, 429, 2197.5, 1091, 14365.5, 10707, 4967.5, 
486.5, 9138.5, 1532, 2569, 14362.5, 8643.4, 12130, 547.5, 351, 
324.5, 2843.5, 183.5, 5182, 8953, 371, 498, 800, 10746.1111111111, 
8471.4, 4177.5, 232.5, 9055.296875, 760, 1228, 9772, 9711.5, 
14949.5, 5650.12162162162, 421.5, 4182, 1711.5, 361.5, 2803.5, 
11720, 258.5, 1756, 1183, 14637.7727272727, 10933, 6201.5, 976.5, 
9925.5, 14207.5, 4360, 10999.5, 5364, 7361, 2624, 289.5, 241.5, 
4469, 415, 952, 9180, 470.5, 571, 935.5, 11995.5, 7702.5, 4157.5, 
401.5, 6990, 784, 1361, 6730.5, 14692.1, 16096.5, 6661, 286.5, 
518.5, 4745.5, 318, 2276, 14160.5, 268, 1078.5, 1214, 19207.3333333333, 
15051.5, 7545, 436.5, 15197.5, 1351, 3741.5, 17206.5, 13227.0294117647, 
17218, 2785, 304.5, 291, 5146, 430.5, 3012.5, 14542.5, 226, 1919, 
1346, 17835.4347826087, 14219.7894736842, 6784.6, 387, 13150.4, 
1189, 3152, 13538), dim = c(20L, 20L), dimnames = list(c("cg00000957", 
"cg00001349", "cg00001583", "cg00002028", "cg00002719", "cg00002837", 
"cg00003202", "cg00003287", "cg00007036", "cg00007898", "cg00008647", 
"cg00009292", "cg00011717", "cg00015930", "cg00016996", "cg00021576", 
"cg00021933", "cg00026222", "cg00027570", "cg00031063"), c("TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A896.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A895.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A894.01A", "TCGA.WN.A9G9.01A", 
"TCGA.V9.A7HT.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q1.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PZ.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PX.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PV.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PU.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PS.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PR.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PO.01A")))


> dput(clin[1:20,])
structure(list(subtype = c("2a", "1a", "1b", "1a", "1a", "1b", 
"2b", "2b", "2a", "1a", "2b", "1b", "1c", "2b", "2a", "2b", "1b", 
"2b", "2b", "1c"), age = c("61", "58", "55", "63", "68", "62", 
"74", "57", "55", "67", "88", "60", "64", "72", "64", "76", "62", 
"84", "60", "80")), row.names = c("TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A896.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A895.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A894.01A", "TCGA.WN.A9G9.01A", "TCGA.V9.A7HT.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9Q1.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PZ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PX.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PV.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PU.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PS.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PR.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PO.01A"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please dput the data for variable `ctl1` as well. Thanks.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101279/warning-in-xtfrm-data-framex-cannot-xtfrm-data-frames-error-while-ordering ... I *suspect* that your `rfit2` object may have more than one column that has a name that matches pattern "p_"?

Comment: @br00t added information on how to get `ctl1`

Comment: Please dput the data for `rgSet` as well, please. Also: `rownames(clin.info) <- clin.info$Sample.ID` do you actually mean `rownames(clin) <- clin$Sample.ID` ?